# Most efficient way to call a method from another class

Tags: java, methods

Let's say I have ClassOne and ClassTwo.

ClassTwo has a method

```
public static void helloWorld() {
    do something();
};
```

Usually I would call the method helloWorld in ClassTwo from ClassOne like this:

```
ClassTwo classTwo = new ClassTwo ();
classTwo.helloWorld();
```

But I can also do it like this:

```
ClassTwo.helloWorld();
```

Is one way preferable to the other? And if so, why?

I hardly ever see someone calling a method like this, but it seems like an efficient way to do so.

Comment: How can you call the method like `ClassTwo.helloWorld()` as helloWorlsd() is not a static method

Comment: The second one only works if the method is `static`

Comment: Edited my code to include the static keyword.

Comment: Do you still have questions, we would be happy to help but in case your query is resolved you can choose and mark the answer as accepted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the method is defined as `static` it *should* be invoked using class reference, you can invoke it using object reference but its not preferred and also not needed.

If the method is not static but simply its an instance method then you *must*  invoke it using a object reference.

Intance method and fields belong to a particular object. You need an object to access instance methods and fields. Using class reference can not access non static methods.

Static methods belong to the class. All objects of the class share common behavior of the method. static methods can not be overridden. They can be accessed by class reference.

*To define a method static you can use `static` keyword*.

Comment: You can even call it from a null reference. Shouldn't, but may.

Answer (score 1):

Change ClassTwo method as static,

```
public static void helloWorld() {
 do something();
};
```

Now you can call like this:

```
ClassTwo.helloWorld();
```

Answer (score 1):

`ClassTwo.helloWorld()` is a static method. This version can only make use of static variables of `ClassTwo`; it cannot use any instance variables. You should use the static version if the method does not need instance variables.

If the method needs to use instance variables, you obviously need to use an instance method.